# Python Dataframe index as a tuple of XY Coordinates

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, gps, coordinates

My function `collectHUC` takes XY coordinates and builds a dictionary of HUC codes named `stationsXY`  for 1000 stations. The `keys` are tuples like `('41.462605 ', '-74.387089')` with `values` like `0202000600`. This process takes time, so I convert `stationsXY` to a DataFrame and save it as follows for later use:

```
xy = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(stationsXY, orient='index')
xy.to_csv('xy_huc.csv', index=False)
```

Here is the issue, when reading back the file `xy_huc.csv` with

```
xy_coor = pd.read_csv('xy_huc.csv', index_col=0, header=None)
```

The DataFrame `xy_coor` has 2 columns, column 0 for the XY coordinates and column 1 for HUC codes, by setting column 0 as the index, the index format is `string` now and not `tuple`. I have tried these so far:

1. Read the csv file, setting the index as a multi-index from the column

   ```
   xy_coor = pd.read_csv('xy_huc.csv', index_col=0, header=None)
   xy = pd.DataFrame(xy_coor, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(xy_coor.index))
   ```

   but I have got this error

   ```
   TypeError: Expected tuple, got str
   ```
2. Read the csv with `index_col=False`, set the index to column zero

   ```
   xy_coor = pd.read_csv('xy_huc.csv', index_col=False, header=None)
   xy = pd.DataFrame(stations_xy, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(xy_coor[0]))
   ```

   but `xy` indexes are in this form

[xy DataFrame for point 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDUIh.jpg)

I am willing to retrieve the file in the same format it was saved on. Any suggestions/recommendations are appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this but I think the easiest way would be to save x and y as separate columns.

Another way would be to parse the tuple string for example:

```
def back_to_tuple(input_string):
    # remove punctuation but not comma 
    punctuation = "(/')"
    for punc in punctuation:
        input_string = input_string.replace(punc, '') 

    # split on comma -> list 
    input_string = input_string.split(',')

    # split on comma -> list 
    input_string = input_string.split(',')

    return input_string
```

You could as well save the xy tuple as a string separated with ';':

```
def tuple_to_string(input_tuple)
    return ';'.join(input_tuple)
```

And than retrieve it like so:

```
def back_to_tuple(input_string):
    return tuple(input_string.split(';'))
```

Answer (score 0):

why not convert the lat and long into a concatenated string then index it.  When you use the index later split the string.